# Delimiter a List<byte[]> after every array inside the list

Tags: ios, arrays, sqlite, xamarin.ios

Currently I am trying to store images in an SQLite DB and I have it working with one but I want to be able to store multiple Byte arrays inside the SQLite DB in one cell of the DB. 
So to achieve this I have set up a list which contains multiple Byte Arrays. What I want to be able to do is add some sort of delimiter after every array inside the list so that when I retrieve the data back from the DB I can use the delimiters to split the List into the different byte arrays which I can then use for my table to show the different images.

I a bit stuck on how to do this so hopefully somebody can help.

This is the only thing I have come up with but really does not work at all (Still pretty new to this) Im using this to split the Byte array list into separate arrays and after each one appending a forward slash and then storing it in a new array to be added to the DB:

```
private byte[] SplitListAndReturnByteArray(List<byte[]> list)
    {
        int count = 0;

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            FormResults.finalByteArray.SetValue(item, count);
            count++;
            FormResults.finalByteArray.SetValue("/", count);
            count++;
        }
        return FormResults.finalByteArray;
    }
```

Comment: storing images in the db is usually a bad idea - storing multiple images in a single column seems like a REALLY bad idea.  Is there a really compelling reason you need to do it this way?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jason. To be fair theres no real reason for me needing to store them all in one column, it was more for neatness. The reason for storing it in the DB is because I may need to reload them images after closing down the app and coming back to it another day. The basis of the app is you can fill in a form which saves all the results to the DB, this includes storing images. I dont want them on the device as there could end up being hundreds of photos. What would be your suggestion? (Its an offline app)

Comment: storing them in the db is still "on the device".  I would just store them in a file folder and in the db just keep a pointer to the file path, not the image data itself

Comment: Ok that sounds great! I wasn't sure about storing images in a DB anyway because its a lot of data which I guess is the reason? I will probably store them in the tmp folder and when Ive finished with them, delete them. Is it ok to do it this way? I dont need any reference in the DB this way.